# Using points on a line to find the number of segments

Tags: geometry

I think this is an extremely problem, but my answer (6) is different from what answer sheet says- choice A. I wonder whether I am totally wrong on the concept. Thank you very much for help!

Problem: A, B, C and D are four distinct points on a line. Using these 4 points, how many segments can be named?

A) 12, B) 8, C) 3, D) 9, E) None of these

Comment: I guess segment AB would be considered different from segment BA then.

Comment: This is an idiodic question because the answer depends on a definition which the question does not supply.  Is $AB$ the same segment as $BA$ or not?  Reasonable people my have different opinions about what "the same" means here.  If you say that of course $BA$ is different than $AB$ since I named it in the other order, then the answer is 12.  If you say"well, I could have labeled the various segments m,n,p,q,r,s -- does that give me 6 more segments I can name -- of course not" then the answer is 6.  It appears as if the test maker is both wrong and certain he is right: a bad combination.

Comment: By definition, AB and BA are the same segment, right?

Comment: I suggest you list the question exactly as it appears in your text.

Comment: NoChance, I copied the question exactly. Now, I believe test maker is wrong.

Comment: LOL - I like playing the conceptual smart-ass. How about adding open versus closed line segments into the mix?!?

Answer (score 1):

Just write down $A,B,C,D$ in order. Since these are distinct points and are on the same line, we can construct $AB,AC,AD,BC,BD,CD$, all of which are distinct. Hence the answer could be $6$.

Alternately, note that a choice of line segment, up to order, is equivalent to a choice of two points out of four (all choices were enumerated above). Therefore, the answer is also $\binom{4}{2} = 6$ up to order.

It's possible that the segment $\overline{BA}$ could be considered different from the segment $\overline{AB}$ due to reversed order of traversal, which would give you $6*2=12$ segments. Hence the answer is $a$ or $e$ depending upon whether your segments differ on the basis of order of traversal or not, which you will need to clarify from the source of the this problem.